# Mongoose. Correct Increment rounded to 2 digits

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose: v5.11.11, Nodejs: v12.18.3

```js
const Schema = new Schema({ 
    total: {
        type: Number,
        set: v => Math.round(v * 100) / 100,
        default: 8.01,
    }
```

```js
let myController = (id, addValue) => model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $inc: { total: addValue } })
```

```js
myController(111, 0.29)
```

We get a value in the db   { **total**: **8.299999999999999** } instead 8.30

Answer (score 0):

For solution, your `setter` won't be triggerred if you use `findByIdAndUpdate`, instead you need query the object, edit it and then save it.

Followings are the explaination about why 8.01 + 0.29 != 8.30.

JavaScript numbers are always stored as [double precision floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), following the international IEEE 754 standard. That's why floating point arithmetic is not always 100% accurate!

Let's dig into it. We can transform a decimal number to binary like this:

```js
// output: "1000.010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101"
8.30.toString(2)
```

As you can see, there is 52 number chars totally.

We can transform binary back to decimal using following functions:

```js
function transformIntegerPart(str) {
    let ret = 0;
    let len = str.length;
    str.split('').forEach((d, i) => {
        if (d === '1') ret += Math.pow(2, len - i - 1);
    });
    return ret;
}
function transformDecimalPart(str) {
    let ret = 0;
    str.split('').forEach((d, i) => {
        if (d === '1') ret += Math.pow(2, -1 - i);
    });
    return ret;
}

// for 8.30,
// real integer part is
transformIntegerPart('1000') // output: 8
// real decimal part is
transformDecimalPart('010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101') // output: 0.3000000000000007 (not actually, javascript adjust this precision automatically)

// so, the real 8.30 in javascript is 8.3000000000000007...
8.30.toPrecision(20) // output: 8.3000000000000007105
```

Now, we can answer your question:

```js
// output: "1000.0000001010001111010111000010100011110101110000101"
8.01.toString(2);
// output: "0.010010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111"
0.29.toString(2);

let integerPart = transformIntegerPart('1000') + transformIntegerPart('0');
console.log(integerPart); // output: 8

let decimalPart = transformDecimalPart('0000001010001111010111000010100011110101110000101') + transformDecimalPart('010010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111');
console.log(decimalPart); // output: 0.29999999999999977

// output: 8.299999999999999
console.log(integerPart + decimalPart);
```